# Version of Ubuntu being used in a docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to figure out the version of Ubuntu being used in a docker container.

This [Verfiy the version of ubuntu running in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003194/verfiy-the-version-of-ubuntu-running-in-a-docker-container) mentions `cat /etc/lsb-release` which gives:

```
cat: can't open '/etc/lsb-release': No such file or directory
```

and `uname -r` gives:

```
3.13.0-119-generic
```

FWIW, `uname -a` gives:

```
Linux <container id> 3.13.0-119-generic #166-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 3 12:18:55 UTC 2017 x86_64 Linux
```

Any ideas what version of Ubuntu it might be? Or how else I can find this out?

Comment: maybe use this stack: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try `lsb-release -a` or `cat /etc/issue`

Answer (score 0):

Just `docker history --no-trunc your_image` will show, among other things the `FROM ...` line